# How to reset/ start a new polygon with embeded matplotlib in pyqt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pyside2, matplotlib-widget

I am trying to create a polygon selector in my PySide2 application. Selector is working fine, but then I want to add functionality to reset/start new polygon when escape button is pressed. Something similar to this PolygonSelector example, when escape is pressed.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/polygon_selector_demo.html

I tried method .clear() but it does not seems to work for me.

```
import sys

import numpy as np
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import (
    FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import PolygonSelector

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)

        shortcut_clear_selection = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Escape"), self._main)
        shortcut_clear_selection.activated.connect(self.callback_clear_selection)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)

        static_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(static_canvas, self))
        layout.addWidget(static_canvas)

        ax = static_canvas.figure.subplots()
        t = np.linspace(0, 10, 501)
        ax.plot(t, np.tan(t), ".")
        self.poly = PolygonSelector(ax, self.onselect)

    def onselect(self, verts):
        pass

    def callback_clear_selection(self):
        # HERE should be the reset part
        self.poly.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    app.activateWindow()
    app.raise_()
    qapp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that `ESC` key release event is not handled by `PolygonSelector` but Your callback. Therefore, to clear polygon and restart creation of polygon You have to clear polygon data and show selector again. `clear` method was just hiding selector, but polygon data stayed unchanged.

Change Your callback code into this:

```
def callback_clear_selection(self):
    # HERE should be the reset
    self.poly._xs, self.poly._ys = [0], [0]
    self.poly._selection_completed = False
    self.poly.set_visible(True)
```

Now, when You press `ESC`, polygon should be removed and You can start selection of new one.